# Image in flutter_staggered_grid_view not showing up

Tags: flutter

So new to flutter so please excuse the question.  I am trying to use images, within the assets/image dir for the Flutter Staggered Grid View.  I am following along with this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDoR302KSU4).  The app workers and I can see all the pictures that are base on a web URL, However, I am getting a blank square where my picture should be. The error happens in myPhotoList('assets/images/food.jpg'),

Again, new to Flutter so not exactly sure what is needed for the image tag here.

Thanks for any assistance

**pubspec.yaml**

```
flutter:
  assets:
   - assets/images/
```

Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';

class GridPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _GridPageState createState() => _GridPageState();
}

class _GridPageState extends State<GridPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu,), onPressed: () {
          //
        }),
        title: Text("Made In Canada Stuff"),

      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          child: StaggeredGridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
            staggeredTiles: [
              StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
              StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
              StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
              StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
              StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
              StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
              StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
              StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),

            ],
            children: <Widget>[
              myPhotoList(
                  'assets/images/food.jpg'),
              myPhotoList(
                  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550496913-b1a19c3779e9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"),
              myPhotoList(
                  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1525344387229-da3782d11618?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"),
              myPhotoList(
                  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531496074234-6db4f0226092?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"),
              myPhotoList(
                  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522865080725-2a9ea1fcb94e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"),
              captionText("Norway", "Just now"),

              myPhotoList(
                "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534546584494-57363237b97f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"),
              myPhotoList(
                  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521320226546-87b106956014?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"),
              myPhotoList(
                  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486808044402-a7c67ef5ea7b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"),
              myPhotoList(
                  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1482076791374-bbc7876d9213?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"),
              captionText("Mountains", "2 day ago"),

            ],
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),

    );
  }

  Widget captionText(String titleText, String subText) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height:20.0),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Container(
                child: Text(titleText,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 24.0),),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Container(
                child: Text(subText,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey, fontSize: 16.0),),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget myPhotoList(String MyImages) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          image: NetworkImage(
              MyImages),
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In myPhotoList you set image like NetworkImage. Your internal image would be AssetImage(path).

Answer (score 0):

myPhotoList Widget make this

```
Widget myPhotoList(String MyImages) {
    if(MyImages.contains("http")) {
      return Container(
        child: Image.network(MyImages),
      );
    }else{
      return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            image: ExactAssetImage(
                MyImages),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```